# What is the Problem in my solution of Bytelandian Gold Coin Problem CodeChef?

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

My solution is timing out. Can someone point out the reason? The url to the problem is https://www.codechef.com/problems/COINS

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
static  long long int s=0;
int coin(long long int n)
{

    if(n<=11)
    {
        s=s+n;
        return n;
    }
coin(n/2)
coin(n/3)
coin(n/4);

}
int main() 
{ 

    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    long long int  x,y;

 while(cin>>x)
 {
    coin(x);
    printf("%lld\n",s);
    s=0;

 }
}
```

Comment: That just means that it's too slow. You'll just need to improve its performance.

Comment: Why are you using the "magic number" 11?

Comment: @Carcigenicate That's what I am  asking! Why it's slow? btw the solution that I read used a similar approach , he just stored the coin value in a map container

Comment: @alfasin because if the input is less than or equal to 11 then the exchange coins will be less than original.  P.S. Read the question given in the link

Answer (score 0):

With the approach taken in the solution above you'll keep recalculating the same numbers over and over again. The `map` that you mentioned in the comments is a technique called [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), in this technique you're caching your results and so for each number, before calling recursively with `coin(x)` you first check if it's already in your memoization table and if it is you can return the result right away without recalculating it over and over again.

Good luck!